# Activating worksheet based on listbox.listindex(0) value

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

I have a userform with a listbox that is populated with three columns.
The multiselect property is set to single.

When I select or (click) or highlight a row of data in the listbox I want to activate a worksheet that has the same name as listbox1.listindex(0).value.

The listbox is populated with customer information. 400 rows.
The first Column in the listbox is Customer ID.

An example would be customer id = abc123 and I have a worksheet named abc123.

So by highlighting or clicking on the customer it will activate the worksheet based on the customer id in the first column of the listbox.

```vb
Private Sub Listbox_click() 
Dim ws As Worksheet 
'Check that the Customer Id sheet exists: On Error Resume Next 
Set ws = Sheets(Me.ListBox1.ListIndex(0).Value) 
On Error GoTo 0 
If ws Is Nothing Then 'missing: MsgBox ("There is not a sheet with this name: " & Me.ListBox1.ListIndex(0).Value _ & vbCrLf & "Correct and retry") 
    Me.ListBox1.SetFocus 
    Exit Sub 
Else 
       'it exists: 
    ws.Activate 
End With 

End Sub
```

Comment: Please show the code you have so far so we can advice you..

Comment: Aldert...here is the code i have...                                                                             
  Private Sub Listbox_click()

Dim ws As Worksheet

'Check that the Customer Id sheet exists:
On Error Resume Next
Set ws = Sheets(Me.ListBox1.ListIndex(0).Value)
On Error GoTo 0

If ws Is Nothing Then
    'missing:
    MsgBox ("There is not a sheet with this name: " & Me.ListBox1.ListIndex(0).Value _
       & vbCrLf & "Correct and retry")
    Me.ListBox1.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
Else
    'it exists:
    
    ws.Activate

End With

End Sub

Comment: Aldert...i don't know if i posted that right. This is my first time on this site to post anything.

Comment: To post your code inside your question goto the Edit link under the post, click on it, paste the code you want, select all the pasted code and apply CTRL+L to format it as 'vba code' and, then, save it.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try, considering the name of the ListBox as "ListBox1". And in my comment, the correct is to apply CTRL+K, not CTRK+L.

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Sheets(ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex)).Activate
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```